# Dangers/Guarantees for using ByteArrayInputStream to have "Correct" mark/reset behaviour

Tags: java-8, fileinputstream, bufferedinputstream, bytearrayinputstream

The question may be generic but I am trying to understand the major implications here.

I am trying to do some byte code engineering using BCEL library and part of the workflow requires me to read the same byte code file multiple times (from the beginning). The flow is the following

```
// 1. Get Input Stream

// 2. Do some work

// 3. Finish

// 4. Do some other work.
```

At step 4, I will need to reset the mark or get the stream as though it's from beginning. I know of the following choices.

1) Wrap the stream using `BufferedInputStream` - chance of getting "Resetting to invalid mark" IOException

2) Wrap it using ByteArrayInputStream - it always works even though some online research suggests that it's erroneous?

3) Simply call `getInputStream()` if I need to read from the stream again.

I am trying to understand which option would be better for me. I don't want to use BufferedInputStream because I have no clue where the last `mark` is called, so calling `reset` for a higher mark position will cause IOException. I would prefer using ByteArrayInputStream since it requires the minimum code change for me, but could anyone suggest whether option#2 or option#3 will be better?

I  know that implementations for mark() and reset() are different for `ByteArrayInputStream` and `BufferedInputStream` in JDK.

Regards

Comment: so basically you are reading a `File` that turns to be a `.class` file? why not read it once and store that in a byte array for example?

Comment: @Eugene          Yes sir I am doing that already - it works but I am a believer or "Expert opinion" and hoping that there is a catch which I might not have considered. Do you know of anything?

Comment: I only know that using mark and reset is important when you don't want to read your entire input stream; or you want to read the next couple of bytes in order to know what to do next; otherwise reading it into a array is the simplest (and clearest for me)

Comment: @Eugene         okay that helps. So you are saying that calling reset() for `ByteArrayInputStream` should correctly reset it back to position 0 (i mean, beginning) of the stream if I want to restart? i.e. there should not be any erroneous behaviour (because I haven't encountered anything so far ) ?

Comment: well reset will reset it (if markSupported == true) to whatever mark was put, not zero, that's what you probably meant. But yes, if this is supported

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem of `mark`/`reset` is not only that you have to know in advance the maximum amount of data being read between these calls, you also have to know whether the code you’re delegating to will use that feature for itself internally, rendering your mark obsolete. It’s impossible for code using `mark`/`reset` to remember and restore a previous mark for the caller.

So while it would be possible to fix the maximum issue by specifying the total file size as maximum `readlimit`, you can never rely on a working mark when passing the `InputStream` to an arbitrary library function that does not explicitly document to never use the `mark`/`reset` feature internally.

Also, a `BufferedInputStream` getting a `readlimit` matching the total file size would not be more efficient than a `ByteArrayInputStream` wrapping an array holding the entire file, as both end up maintaining a buffer of the same size.

---

The best solution would be to read the entire class file into an array once and directly use the array, e.g. for code under your control or when you have a choice regarding the library (ASM’s `ClassReader` supports using a byte array instead of an `InputStream`, for example).

If you have to feed an `InputStream` to a library function insisting on it, like BCEL, then wrap the byte array into a `ByteArrayInputStream` when needed, but *create a new* `ByteArrayInputStream` each time you have to re-parse the class file. Constructing the new `ByteArrayInputStream` costs nothing, as it is a lightweight wrapper and is reliable, as it does not depend on the state of an older input stream in any way. You could even have multiple `ByteArrayInputStream` instances reading the same array at the same time.

Calling `getInputStream()` again would be an option, if you have to deal with really large files for which buffering the entire contents is not an option, however, this is not the case for class files.

Comment: I am actually wrapping the file contents (byte[]) into `ByteArrayInputStream` and passing that on - minimum change in API - this works for me. Looks like both yourself and @Eugene   have got this in your comments. I am happy with this for now.